# SQL multiple characteristic select on Sub Query

Tags: sql

self taught, first time poster.
I have what seems like it should be basic, but I am having a brain block on getting this to work.  I have two data sets, I want to compare one to the other and find the records that are in Set 1 (Actuals) that are not in set to (Operating Expenses).

```
select distinct vacctcode, vEntityID 
from     tm1_fin_lines_integration 
where    vScenario = '507'
  and    vLineItemType = 'OperatingExpense'
```

This returns a data set that looks like this:

[image: Operating Expense Accounts]

My second query is:

```
select i.property_externalid, i.externalid, r.lineitemtypename
from ivw_Actuals i 
inner join rvw_accounts r on r.accountnumber = i.externalid
where r.LineItemTypeName = 'OperatingExpense'
and i.PropertyAssetId in .
(select vpropid from tm1_fin_lines_integration where vScenario = '507')
```

and returns results like:

[image: Actuals]

I want to find the records that are in the Actuals result set that are not in the Operating Expense Result Set.  I need to match on externalid/vacctcode and vEntityid/Property_ExternalID.

I am just not sure how to match on multiple characteristics.

This query works when I am only looking at one vEntityid/Property_ExternalID, but in practice I will be looking at a data set of hundreds, so I need to be able to find the account code/entity combinations that are in the actuals set that are not in the Operating expense set.

```
select i.property_externalid, 
i.externalid, 
r.lineitemtypename
from ivw_Actuals i 
inner join rvw_accounts r on r.accountnumber = i.externalid
where r.LineItemTypeName = 'OperatingExpense'
and i.PropertyAssetId in 
(select vpropid from tm1_fin_lines_integration where vScenario = '507')
and i.externalid not in
(select distinct vacctcode, vEntityID 
from 
tm1_fin_lines_integration 
where 
vScenario = '507'
and vLineItemType = 'OperatingExpense')
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Show us sample data and expected result. not sure what `are in the Actuals result set that are not in the Operating Expense` mean. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `NOT EXISTS` constraint:

```
select distinct vacctcode, vEntityID 
from 
tm1_fin_lines_integration x
where vScenario = '507'
and vLineItemType = 'OperatingExpense'

AND NOT EXISTS (

        select i.property_externalid, i.externalid, r.lineitemtypename
        from ivw_Actuals i 
        inner join rvw_accounts r on r.accountnumber = i.externalid
        where r.LineItemTypeName = 'OperatingExpense'
        and i.PropertyAssetId in (select vpropid from tm1_fin_lines_integration where vScenario = '507')

        AND i.externalid = x.vacctcode
        AND i.property_externalid = x.vEntityID

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `except` keyword. Like this:

```
select distinct vacctcode, vEntityID 
from     tm1_fin_lines_integration 
where    vScenario = '507'
  and    vLineItemType = 'OperatingExpense'

except

select i.externalid, i.property_externalid
from ivw_Actuals i 
inner join rvw_accounts r on r.accountnumber = i.externalid
where r.LineItemTypeName = 'OperatingExpense'
and i.PropertyAssetId in .
(select vpropid from tm1_fin_lines_integration where vScenario = '507')
```

I had to rearrange and adjust your query to get the fields to match up, and I had to remove one from the select. But this should get you what you need, and from there, you should be able to get any other data required for the relevant records.

If, for whatever reason, that isn't an option, you could also try something like this:

```
select distinct vacctcode, vEntityID, act.*
    from     tm1_fin_lines_integration  fin
    left join (
    select i.externalid, i.property_externalid
    from ivw_Actuals i 
    inner join rvw_accounts r on r.accountnumber = i.externalid
    where r.LineItemTypeName = 'OperatingExpense'
    and i.PropertyAssetId in .
    (select vpropid from tm1_fin_lines_integration where vScenario = '507')
) act on act.externalid = fin.vacctcode and act.property_externalid = fin.vEntityID
    where    vScenario = '507'
      and    vLineItemType = 'OperatingExpense'
      and act.externalid  is null
```

It's rough code, as I don't know exactly what your tables look like, but I believe that should also give you what you need. I tend to try to avoid sub-selects if at all possible, which is why I prefer the first option.

I apologize if I have the records sets backwards, I wasn't quite sure that I followed the way you had it set up. If I do, simply flip around the queries to achieve the required results.